# Error when try start wildfly server and deploy project, using wildfly 10.1.0.Final, hibernate ogm 5.0.10.Final and Cassandra 3.0.9

Tags: hibernate, wildfly-10, hibernate-ogm, maven-deploy-plugin

I have some troubles deploy my project. I am able to start the wildfly server with errors but I cannot deploy my project. Here is the error message:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.1.0.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project aigateway: Failed to execute goal deploy: {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"aigateway.war#JPAService\".**FIRST_PHASE**" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"aigateway.war#JPAService\".**FIRST_PHASE**: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversIntegrator not a subtype
>   [ERROR] Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversIntegrator not a subtype"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"aigateway.war#JPAService\".**FIRST_PHASE**"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined}}}
>   [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>   [ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

It seems to me that there is some compatibility issues with my dependencies. But I don't know what the problem is.

Here is my jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.hibernate.ogm" slot="5.0" services="export" />
        <module name="org.hibernate.ogm.cassandra" slot="main" services="export" />
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.sensorhound</groupId>
<artifactId>aigateway</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>AI Gateway Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jetty.version>9.3.12.v20160915</jetty.version>
    <jersey.version>2.23.2</jersey.version>
    <ogm.version>5.0.4.Final</ogm.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.0.4.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <!-- hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-infinispan</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-cassandra</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
       <version>1.6.1</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- hibernate ogm -->
    <!-- Hibernate OGM Infinispan module; pulls in the OGM core module -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-infinispan</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- standard APIs dependencies - provided in a Java EE container -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Add the Narayana Transactions Manager
     an implementation would be provided in a Java EE container,
     but this works nicely in Java SE as well -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.narayana.jta</groupId>
        <artifactId>narayana-jta</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-transaction-spi</artifactId>
        <version>7.5.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbossjta</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- dependency> <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId> <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId> 
        <version>${jetty.version}</version> </dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fusesource.leveldbjni</groupId>
        <artifactId>leveldbjni-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>aigateway</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And I have there directory under my hibernate directory:

***5.0, commons-annotations, envers, hql, infinispan, jipijapa-hibernate5, main, ogm, search, validator***

To solve this problem, I looked for some jars or directory related to envers in the hibernate directory.

Here is what my module.xml look like in hibernate/5.0/main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.hibernate" slot="5.0">
<resources>
    <resource-root path="hibernate-core-5.0.4.Final.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="hibernate-envers-5.0.4.Final.jar"/>
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="asm.asm"/>
    <module name="com.fasterxml.classmate"/>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.annotation.api"/>
    <module name="javax.enterprise.api"/>
    <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
    <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
    <module name="org.antlr"/>
    <module name="org.dom4j"/>
    <module name="org.javassist"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.spi"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.jandex"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.vfs"/>
    <module name="org.hibernate.commons-annotations"/>
    <module name="org.hibernate.infinispan" services="import" optional="true"/>
    <module name="org.hibernate.jipijapa-hibernate5" services="import"/>
</dependencies>
```

Along with two jars named **hibernate-core-5.0.4.Final.jar, hibernate-envers-5.0.4.Final.jar**.

And I have no jar in hibernate/envers/main, this is the module.xml in hibernate/envers/main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module-alias xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.hibernate.envers" target-name="org.hibernate"/>
```

And there nothing more related to envers in the hibernate directory. So I don't know what the problem is.

Someone please help me!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just solved this problem. For more information:
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/274192

Comment: This is quite a vague answer.